# Can't compile CUDA + OpenGL program on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: linux, macos, opengl, makefile, cuda

I am writing a program that includes OpenGL and CUDA codes at the university and i can run it with Ubuntu Linux. The program has got many dependencies so i use a makefile and when i'm at the university with Linux i have no problems. Yesterday i tried running it on my MacBook at home and it didn't run. I set libraries paths properly, but when i try to compile using the makefile i get the following lines:

```
MBP-di-Nicolo:MATRIX_TEST Nico$ make
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++   -m64  -Xcompiler -g -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64   -g -G -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib   -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker GLUT -o Matrix_test my_utils2.o Matrix_test.o Matrix.o -L/System/Library  -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries  -lGL -lGLU ../../common/lib/darwin/libGLEW.a -L. -lrt
nvlink fatal   : Could not find fatbin in 'my_utils2.o'
nvlink fatal   : elfLink internal error
make: *** [Matrix_test] Error 1
MBP-di-Nicolo:MATRIX_TEST Nico$
```

Here's the makefile:

```
PROGNAME = Matrix_test
#PROGNAME2 = read_file

CC = g++

include ./findcudalib.mk

# Location of the CUDA Toolkit
CUDA_PATH ?= /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5


#DEK_SRC = ../pure-dek/src
#DEK_INCLUDE = -I../pure-dek/include

# internal flags
NVCCFLAGS   := -m${OS_SIZE} 
#NVCCFLAGS   := -m${OS_SIZE} --keep
CCFLAGS     := -g 
NVCCLDFLAGS := -g -G
LDFLAGS     :=

# Extra user flags
EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS   ?=
EXTRA_NVCCLDFLAGS ?=
EXTRA_LDFLAGS     ?=
EXTRA_CCFLAGS     ?=

# OS-specific build flags
ifneq ($(DARWIN),) 
 LDFLAGS += -rpath $(CUDA_PATH)/lib
 CCFLAGS += -arch $(OS_ARCH) $(STDLIB)  
else
 ifeq ($(OS_ARCH),armv7l)
 ifeq ($(abi),gnueabi)
  CCFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=softfp
else
  # default to gnueabihf
  override abi := gnueabihf
  LDFLAGS += --dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
  CCFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard
endif
endif
endif

ifeq ($(ARMv7),1)
NVCCFLAGS += -target-cpu-arch ARM
ifneq ($(TARGET_FS),) 
CCFLAGS += --sysroot=$(TARGET_FS)
LDFLAGS += --sysroot=$(TARGET_FS)
LDFLAGS += -rpath-link=$(TARGET_FS)/lib
LDFLAGS += -rpath-link=$(TARGET_FS)/usr/lib
LDFLAGS += -rpath-link=$(TARGET_FS)/usr/lib/arm-linux-$(abi)
endif
endif

# Debug build flags 
ifeq ($(dbg),1)
  NVCCFLAGS += -g -G
  TARGET := debug
else
  TARGET := release
endif

ALL_CCFLAGS :=
ALL_CCFLAGS += $(NVCCFLAGS)
ALL_CCFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xcompiler ,$(CCFLAGS))
ALL_CCFLAGS += $(EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS)
ALL_CCFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xcompiler ,$(EXTRA_CCFLAGS))

ALL_LDFLAGS :=
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(ALL_CCFLAGS)
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(NVCCLDFLAGS)
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xlinker ,$(LDFLAGS))
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(EXTRA_NVCCLDFLAGS)
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -Xlinker ,$(EXTRA_LDFLAGS))

# Common includes and paths for CUDA
EXT_LIB = /System/Library
INCLUDES  := 
LIBRARIES := -L$(EXT_LIB) 

# Makefile include to help find GL Libraries
EXEC            ?=
include ./findgllib.mk

# OpenGL specific libraries 
ifneq ($(DARWIN),)
# Mac OSX specific libraries and paths to include
 LIBRARIES += -L/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Libraries 
 LIBRARIES += -lGL -lGLU ../../common/lib/darwin/libGLEW.a
 ALL_LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -framework -Xlinker GLUT
else
 LIBRARIES += -L../../common/lib/$(OSLOWER)/$(OS_ARCH) $(GLLINK)
 #LIBRARIES += -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lXxf86vm -lXcursor -lGL -lpthread -ldl -lGLEW -lglut -lGLU
 LIBRARIES += -lglui -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lX11 -lXi -lXmu -lGLEW
endif

  ################################################################################

 # CUDA code generation flags
ifneq ($(OS_ARCH),armv7l)
GENCODE_SM10    := -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11
endif
GENCODE_SM10    := -gencode arch=compute_11,code=sm_11
GENCODE_SM20    := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20
GENCODE_SM30    := -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode          arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\"
GENCODE_FLAGS   := $(GENCODE_SM11) $(GENCODE_SM20) $(GENCODE_SM30) 

################################################################################

# Target rules
all: build

build: $(PROGNAME) 


my_utils2.o: my_utils2.cu my_utils2.h
$(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) $(ALL_CCFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

Matrix.o: Matrix.cu Matrix.h my_utils2.h
$(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) $(ALL_CCFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

Matrix_test.o: Matrix_test.cu my_utils2.h
$(NVCC) $(INCLUDES) $(ALL_CCFLAGS) $(GENCODE_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<


$(PROGNAME): my_utils2.o Matrix_test.o Matrix.o  
$(NVCC) $(ALL_LDFLAGS) -o $@ $+ $(LIBRARIES) -L. -lrt
mkdir -p ./bin/$(OS_ARCH)/$(OSLOWER)/$(TARGET)$(if $(abi),/$(abi))
cp $@ ./bin/$(OS_ARCH)/$(OSLOWER)/$(TARGET)$(if $(abi),/$(abi))

run: build
./$(PROGNAME)

clean:
rm -f *.o
#   rm -rf ./bin/$(OS_ARCH)/$(OSLOWER)/$(TARGET)$(if $(abi),/$(abi))/mergeSort

clobber: clean
```

I didn't modify the makefile used for Linux, except for two lines (the following are the old ones):

```
# Location of the CUDA Toolkit
CUDA_PATH ?= "/usr/local/cuda-7.5"

# Common includes and paths for CUDA
EXT_LIB = /usr/local/lib
```

Could you help me please?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I don't think g++ is a [supported compiler for CUDA 7.5 on mac OS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#system-requirements).  I'm not that familiar with Mac development, so if this Makefile calling out g++ is actually somehow invoking clang under the hood, then you can ignore this comment, however I would expect `-ccbin clang++` not `-ccbin g++`, something like what is shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ04A.png)

Comment: What's the cmline of compiling `my_utils2.o` and other .o files? I can see only the cmdline of how you link them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `nvcc` to link the final program. In fact I strongly advise against it. `nvcc` should be used for compiling `.cu` files only and the rest be left to gcc/g++/clang.

In general it's a bad idea to force `nvcc` into using a particular compiler. Just let it choose its default. I don't see in the Makefile you posted (it's likely in `findcuda.mk`) the definition for variable `NVCC`, I suspect that there the `--ccbin` flag is configured.

Furthermore in MacOS X OpenGL is covered by the `OpenGL` framework. The libraries libGL/libGLU are there for support programs running through an X11 server (which is available in MacOS X), but the X11/GLX/OpenGL support of MacOS X is a compatibility layer and will not support CUDA.

Hence I suggest you change as following:

```
LIBRARIES += ../../common/lib/darwin/libGLEW.a
LDFLAGS += -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL

all: build install

$(PROGNAME): my_utils2.o Matrix_test.o Matrix.o  
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $+ $(LIBRARIES) -L.

install: $(PROGNAME)
    mkdir -p ./bin/$(OS_ARCH)/$(OSLOWER)/$(TARGET)$(if $(abi),/$(abi))
    cp $@ ./bin/$(OS_ARCH)/$(OSLOWER)/$(TARGET)$(if $(abi),/$(abi))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Now i only get "ld: library not found for -lrt". How can i fix it?

Comment: @NicolòCogno: Drop that `-lrt` for MacOS X builds. Linking with `librt` is required only on *some* operating systems and MacOS X does not belong to this set. I just had to Google that myself. See the diff in my answer edit.

Comment: @NicolòCogno: Also see http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2008/Oct/msg00001.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I did it, but now i get "ld: -rpath can only be used when targeting Mac OS X 10.5 or later". Do you know why?

Comment: @NicolòCogno: Well the error message is pretty clear about it. `rpath` is a field in \*nix executables that specifies locations where the dynamic linker shall look for dynamic objects at runtime (in addition to the standard paths). And the error message tells you that this feature is not supported for OS X 10.5 or later. So you must remove the flag, setting an rpath from the build configuration for MacOS X. Look for all `rpath` flags in the Makefile and remove them. But keep in mind that all required libraries/dynamic objects have to be in standard locations then, for this to work.

Comment: All the rpath will be autoset if i just remove the flags or should i write something instead?